# Read raw request body of RestRequest

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am using RestSharp a lot in my project, and I recently needed to implement a request authenticator that calculates a SHA256 hash of request body, and adds it into the `Authorization` request header.
I came up with the following code:

```
public class HashAuthenticator : IAuthenticator
{
  public ValueTask Authenticate(IRestClient client, RestRequest request)
  {
     if (request.Parameters.Any(x => x.Type == ParameterType.RequestBody))
     {
         byte[] content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request.Parameters.First(x => x.Type == ParameterType.RequestBody).Value.ToString());
         if (content.Length > 0)
         {
               hash = Hash.SHA256(content);
               request.AddHeader("Authorization", hash);
         }
      }
  }
}
```

The above method of extracting request body works well when the original request body is JSON and it is constructed in the following way:

```
var request = new RestRequest("", Method.Post);
request.AddJsonBody(new { someKey = "value" });
// or request.AddParameter("application/json", "{ abc: xyz }", ParameterType.RequestBody)
```

However if I try to initialize a request with a `x-www-form-urlencoded` body like this:

```
// This approach is used to initialize requests with x-www-form-urlencoded content type
// and automatically encode param names and values
var request = new RestRequest("", Method.Post);
request.AddParameter("SomeKey", "SomeValue", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
```

Then the above approach does not work. Although the actual HTTP request gets sent with the expected `x-www-form-urlencoded` content type and the expected body `SomeKey=SomeValue`, the RestRequest object (that I use in the authenticator code) does not contain a parameter with `ParameterType.RequestBody`.

Is there a universal way that would allow me to extract the raw request body from `RestRequest` regardless of the way how I added body parameters to `RestRequest`?

Answer (score 0):

The request content is built with this helper class: [RequestContent.cs on RestSharp GitHub](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/dev/src/RestSharp/Request/RequestContent.cs).

Unfortunately for you, the Authenticator is called BEFORE this helper class is called. However, newer versions of RestSharp added interceptors that could help you calculate your required hash... See [RestSharp Request OnBeforeRequest property on GitHub](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/dev/src/RestSharp/Request/RestRequest.cs#L175).

You ought to be able to replace the Authorization header with whatever you need for this scenario.